# command not found: django-admin-version

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm a beginner in programming. I installed Django, but it shows `zsh: command not found: django-admin` and `zsh: command not found: pip`

This is my code

```
MacBook-Air ~ % python3 -m pip --version
pip 22.1.2 from /Users/myname/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
MacBook-Air ~ % pip list
zsh: command not found: pip
MacBook-Air ~ % python -m pip install Django
zsh: command not found: python
MacBook-Air ~ % python3 -m pip install Django
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: Django in ./Library/Python/3.8/bin/django (4.2.dev20220601123622)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref>=3.4.1 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from Django) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from Django) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.zoneinfo in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from Django) (0.2.1)
MacBook-Air ~ % django-admin --version
zsh: command not found: django-admin
```

---

I turn off this terminal then start a new one.
when I write `(base) chenkaizhun@chenkaizhundeMacBook-Air ~ % pip list` it works!
But dose " (base)" means I'm in Virtual environment?

Comment: first make sure that python is installed correctly

Comment: (base) appears generally when you installed Anaconda. Base become basic environment of Anaconda and it includes most python libraries. I think python3 installed correctly but there is a problem with python. I prefer check Python/Python3 installed correctly